# Submit trigger failing Jquery within dialog (modal)

Tags: jquery, html, triggers

I'm entirely sure how to describe my problem in it's entirety. However, I'll give it a shot.

I have several triggers assigned to HTML elements using Jquery. Trigger 1, validates items exclusively for this particular form. The Second trigger is triggers after the validation of Trigger 1 is determined.

What is happening, you will see if the code below, `if ($(".Reason").val() == 4) {` brings up a Dialog window, which will in turn give two options, yes/no. Yes will call trigger 2 (submit) otherwise close for corrections...

If the condition is not met, trigger2 (submit) processes correctly and posts the form. However it's like a `return false` is preventing if the condition is met.

Some of the lines are irreverent, but I left them in there...If consensus is to remove, i will.

Sorry for the vast amount of code.

Hope someone can help!

```
$(".validateForm").click(function () {

        if ($(".Reason").val() == 4) {
            //bankingModal
            ExpectedAmount = $(".CloseAmount").val();  
            cashTotal = parseInt($(".cashtotal").val());                  
            chequeTotal = parseInt($(".chequeTotal").val());         

            formTotal = cashTotal + chequeTotal;
            formTotal = parseFloat(formTotal).toFixed(2);

            if (formTotal !== ExpectedAmount ) {
                $(".bankModal").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 210,
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    position: 'center',
                    buttons: {
                        'Yes - Submit': function () {
                             $('.submit').click()
                            $(this).dialog("close");

                        },
                        'No - Cancel': function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            //submitBanking();
            $('.submit').click()
        }
        return false;
})

// The following is the second trigger.

$('.submit').click(function () {

// Unset error

        formErr = false;
        window.onbeforeunload = null;

        // Validation for Change Request
        if ($(".outgoing").length > 0) {
            if (validateChangeRequest()) {
                formErr = true;
            }
        }

        // If text box is empty change values to 0.00
        $('.cashSum', '.cashSumOut').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).val('0.00');
            }

        });

        // Check if numeric values are ok prior to submit.
        $(".cashAmount").each(function () {
            if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
                modal("", "Only numbers are permitted");
                formErr = true;
            }
            if (checkNegatives($(this))) {
                modal($(this), "Negative values are not permitted");
                formErr = true;
            }
        });
        if (formErr) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($("#cashCheque").length != 0) {          
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the dialog every single time it satisfies the condition.

Just create it once in `DOM ready handler` and just open the dialog when the condition is satisfied.

```
$(".validateForm").click(function() {

    if ($(".Reason").val() == 4) {
        //bankingModal
        ExpectedAmount = $(".CloseAmount").val();
        cashTotal = parseInt($(".cashtotal").val());
        chequeTotal = parseInt($(".chequeTotal").val());

        formTotal = cashTotal + chequeTotal;
        formTotal = parseFloat(formTotal).toFixed(2);

        if (formTotal !== ExpectedAmount) {
            $(".bankModal").dialog('open');
        }
    } else {
        //submitBanking();
        $('.submit').click()
    }
    return false;
});

$(".bankModal").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 210,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    autoOpen : false,
    buttons: {
        'Yes - Submit': function() {
            $('.submit').click()
            $(this).dialog("close");

        },
        'No - Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});​
```

**UPDATE**

Supposed to submit the form when no error

```
if (formErr) {
    return false;
}
if ($("#cashCheque").length != 0) {          
    return false;
}

$('form').submit(); // submit when no errors
```

Comment: Good suggestion, however, the $('submit').click() still doesn't post for the form it mealy processes the trigger with no posting...

Comment: I see that you are not submitting the form anywhere.. $('form').submit()

Comment: This works, however, the .submit class is associated with an ASP Button with an OnClick, which calls a C# codebehind function.

Comment: It seems to work if I take out the modal $(".bankModal").dialog('open'); and just put $('.submit')...

Comment: If thats the case .click() will fire the client side click event , but not the server event